# How to debug naked urls not working for some regions issue

Tags: no-www, google-app-engine

Our site is hosted on Google appengine and we have configured a cname property for our www subdomain that points to googlehosted link. But some of our users from a certain region reports that non WWW urls don't work for them while both www and naked url works for most users.

I was wondering where to start to debug this issue.

Comment: how long since you configured the cname?  Have you given it plenty of time to propagate?

Comment: about 2-3 weeks ago

Answer (score 1):

It should have propagated by now.  I'm guessing there's a propagation error somewhere in the affected region.  Are your familiar with a command line versions of NSLookup?  Windows has one built into the OS.

I would set the nameserver in NSLookup to match your client's nameservers.  Then test cname resolution with NSLookup.  Look for the upstream NS records.  Change the name server to the upstream nameserver  in NSLookup and test resolution of your cname record again.  You should be able to walk backwards up the DNS tree by specifying the nameserver up each level to determine if and where there's a propagation error.